# Datatables fails when trying to load 70000 records

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a jQuery `datatable` that can be provided with over 70K records.

Unfortunately, the `datatable` fails to load anything over 20K records.

I am using the option `deferRender` in a workaround attempt, to no avail.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'api/portmbs.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data);

        var table = $('#example1').DataTable({
            "data": jsonObject,
            "columns": [
                {"data": "column_one"},
                {"data": "column_two"},
                // more columns...
            ],
            "iDisplayLength": 25,
            "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
            "paging": true,
            "scrollY": 550,
            "scrollX": true,
            "bDestroy": true,
            "stateSave": true,
            "autoWidth": true,
            "deferRender": true
        });
    },
    error: function(jqHHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        $('#loadingDiv').hide();
        $('#errorModal').modal('show');
        $('.message').text('There was an error conducting your search. Please try again.');
        return false;       
        console.log('fail: '+ errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Using the above, an error is triggered with the corresponding error message:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)

When I add a `10000` limit to the query that generate the data, the `datatable` is successfully rendered.

What am I missing to get the `deferRender` option to successfully run and defer the loading of 70K records?

Comment: Who needs to see 70K rows all at once?

Comment: *«The 500 Internal Server Error is a very general HTTP status code that means something has gone wrong on the website's server...»* [ref](https://www.lifewire.com/500-internal-server-error-explained-2622938)

Comment: I have faced some similar a time ago, my problem was that the data I tried to get from the server overflowed the `memory_limit` variable of `PHP` (I think the default is `128MB` on `php.ini`). You can try increasing this value (mine is 512MB now), but take care of read more here: https://haydenjames.io/understanding-php-memory_limit/

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette - When I add the limit of 10000, I no longer get the error.

Comment: @D.Smania - I didn't think of that.  I will look into the memory_limit to see what I can do.

Comment: @JohnBeasley Ok, tellme if that helps, also, remember to restart the server when you change the configuration file.

Comment: @D.Smania - I made the update, and now 70000+ records show in the datatable.  There is one thing I noticed... on the server, the CPU usage spikes to over 70%.  This may not be good if 20+ people all happen to conduct the same type of search, which I doubt they will.

Comment: @JohnBeasley The real solution for this case will be use `server-side` processing and on every pagination/ordering/filtering on the table make a post to the server for get the new data, consider this a temporary workaround, but not a final solution. I will made an answer in case this is helpful to other people.

Comment: @D.Smania - server-side processing may be what I need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced a similar issue some time ago, in my case the server error was caused by an overflow on the `PHP` `memory_limit` variable. The default value (inside `php.ini`) is `128MB` so there is a possibility that these `70000+ rows` of data you are getting overflows that limit.

As a temporary workaround, you can try to increase this limit changing the configuration of the `php.ini` file on the server and then restarting the server. My current configuration is:

```
; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
; XXX: Increased from 128 to 512.
memory_limit = 512M
```

You can read more about this on next links:

**(1)** http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit

**(2)** https://haydenjames.io/understanding-php-memory_limit/

Like I say, the previous solution should be considered like a workaround only. The real solution for these type of problems will be using [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side) and on every pagination, ordering or filtering on the table make a post to the server for handle these actions and get the new data rendering the `datatable` again. There is an implementation of server-side processing available on `DataTables` examples, check it on next link:

**(1)** [Server Side Processing Class Example](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php)

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I will definitely look into the server-side processing.

Comment: You are welcome, it is also a pending task for me since it requires a lot of changes on my current project.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        serverSide: true,
        ordering: false,
        searching: false,
        ajax: function ( data, callback, settings ) {
            var out = [];

            for ( var i=data.start, ien=data.start+data.length ; i<ien ; i++ ) {
                out.push( [ i+'-1', i+'-2', i+'-3', i+'-4', i+'-5' ] );
            }

            setTimeout( function () {
                callback( {
                    draw: data.draw,
                    data: out,
                    recordsTotal: 5000000,
                    recordsFiltered: 5000000
                } );
            }, 50 );
        },
        scrollY: 200,
        scroller: {
            loadingIndicator: true
        },
        stateSave: true
    } );
} );
```