# IE 11 browser is freezing with 60000 rows to display with JQuery Datatable

Tags: tomcat, internet-explorer, datatable, datatables, out-of-memory

We r trying to display 60000 records using jquery data table but facing the below issue
any suggestion how to fix this.

It's working with 30000 records but facing memory issue with 60000 records. JVM headspace is 10GB
RAM is 32 GB
[image]

Comment: DataTables is not a substitute for a database. I can't think of any good reason why someone would need all 60,000 records loaded into the browser at the same time. Your best bet is to investigate [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side)

Comment: Does the issue also occur in other browsers? 60000 rows of data are too many. For similar   issue, you can refer to the accepted answers in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158102/loading-large-amount-of-data-into-memory-most-efficient-way-to-do-this) and in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53598609/datatables-fails-when-trying-to-load-70000-records). I agree with the comment above, the real solution is using server-side processing.